# neo4j Cypher IF THEN ELSE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to read a json file having this structure:

```
{
    "source":"source name",
    "target":"target name",
    "targettype":"targettype",
}
```

The nodes source and target are already loaded in my graph. 
And they have distinct labels.
Target names are not unique but each duplicate would be in relationship with a different targettype

There are then two distinct groups of target node, those that have a type and those that do not have a type; in the graph those nodes have distinct labels
please note that when a node has no type, the json value for targetype is null

The json file is meant to load the relationship between the source and the target using the name

I am pretty lost on how to achieve it.
As I need a IF THEN ELSE
I TRIED TO USE two FOREACH (ignoreme ) followed by the MATCH but this is not allowed
.....

The pseudo code would be

```
LOAD lines from json
WITH blah blah blah
UNWIND blah blah blah
IF targettype is NULL THEN
  MATCH (n:source_name)--(sourcetype)
  MATCH (m:NULL_TARGET_LABEL target_name)
ELSE
  MATCH (n: source_name)--(sourcetype)
  MATCH (m:NON_NULL_TARGET_LABEL target_name)--(targettype)
END
MERGE (n)-[:TIGHT_IT_TO]_(m)
RETURN *
```

Comment: Where does sourcetype come from? what does `(n:source_name)--(sourcetype)` mean?

Comment: I start with loading data from json  so source_name and sourcetype contain the values loaded from the json

MATCH(n: {name:source_name)}--(sct: {name:sourcetype})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The APOC procedure [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/cypher-execution/run-cypher-scripts/#_when_procedures) should be helpful. For example:

```
...
MATCH (n:source_name)--(sourcetype)
CALL apoc.do.when(
  targettype is NULL,
  "MATCH (m:NULL_TARGET_LABEL {name: target_name}) RETURN COLLECT(m) AS ms",
  'MATCH (m:NON_NULL_TARGET_LABEL {name:target_name})--(targettype) RETURN COLLECT(m) AS ms',
  {target_name:target_name, targettype:targettype}) YIELD value
UNWIND value.ms AS m
MERGE (n)-[:TIGHT_IT_TO]-(m)
...
```

Comment: Hi Cybersam
Thank you very much. that works fine

What then if I need to pass the label as a parameter, to the MATCH?